# Constructing a vector of custom type with istream_iterator

Tags: c++, serialization, stl, fstream, stdvector

I want to write and read STL Vector of my class type to binary file, but don't understand what's wrong with istream_iterator.
Project rules disallow to use text files, 
same as third-party libraries like Boost.

This is Book.h:

```
class Book{
    public:
    Book(const std::vector<Book>& in_one_volumes,const std::string& title,
    const std::string& author,const int pagecount,const int price,const std::string& date);
    private:
    std::vector<Book> inOneVolumes;
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    int pagecount;
    int price;
    std::string date;
};
```

This is write method:

```
void writeBook(std::vector<Book> books) {
    std::ofstream binOut("book.bin", std::ios::binary);
    std::copy(books.begin(), books.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<Book>(binOut, "\n")); 
}
```

And i want to read like this:

```
std::vector<Book> readBooks() {
    std::vector<Book> toReturn;
    std::ifstream BinIn("book.bin", std::ios::binary);
    std::istream_iterator<Book> file_iter(BinIn);
    std::istream_iterator<Book> end_of_stream;
    std::copy(file_iter, end_of_stream, std::back_inserter(toReturn));
    return toReturn;    
}
```

Compiller says -- Book:no appropriate default constructor available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::istream_iterator<Book>` uses `operator>>(std::istream&, Book&)` to read data into objects. Since this `operator>>` requires an existing `Book` object as parameter (to write the data into), the iterator has to construct one before it can dump the data from the stream into it, and for this it requires a default constructor.

Your `Book` class does not have one. The easiest solution to the problem would be to give it one.

In the event that this is not an option (e.g., if `Book` as to guarantee invariants that a default constructor cannot provide), you could introduce an intermediate data transfer class that is default-constructible, can be filled with data via `operator>>`, and can be converted to `Book`. Sketch:

```
class TransferBook {
public:
  // To read data from stream
  friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, TransferBook &dest);

  // Conversion to Book. Use the non-default Book constructor here.
  operator Book() const {
    return Book(all the data);
  }

private:
  // all the data
};

...

std::vector<Book> books;
std::ifstream file;

// Note that books contains Books and the iterator reads TransferBooks.
// No Book is default-constructed, only TransferBooks are.
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<TransferBook>(file),
          std::istream_iterator<TransferBook>(),
          std::back_inserter(books));
```

To be sure, this approach is rather cumbersome and essentially duplicates code, and probably it is less hassle to give `Book` the default-constructor. However, if `Book` cannot be changed in this way, this is a possible workaround.